# Swift 5 navigationItem.title как отобразить данные с двух разных переменных firstName и secondName?

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller

Есть вот такой класс в Firebase

```
class User {
    
    var uid: String!
    var firstName: String!
    var secondName: String!
    var profileImage: String!
    
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        
        
        self.uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
        self.secondName = dictionary["secondName"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImage = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        
    }
}

func fetchCurrentUser() {
        
        Firestore.firestore().fetchCurrentUser { (user, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Ошибка получения пользователя", err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.user = user
            print(user?.firstName ?? "")
            
            self.navigationItem.title = user?.firstName
        }
    }
```

Не пойму как прописать что бы в navigationItem.title отображалось firstName + " " + secondName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigationItem.title = "\(user?.firstName ?? "") \(user?.secondName ?? "")"
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!